# iOS (iPhone/iPad) App Store - Missing developer/seller name in "app detail" page

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

It's hard to explain this but I've noticed that other apps have this so I will use them as examples:

If you search "Angry Birds" on the App Store (on iPhone), you will see it under the name "Clickgamer.com" but if the tap on it to take it to the "app details" page where you download the app where it is listed under a different name - "Clickgamer Technologi...".

If you search "Angry Birds Rio" on the App Store, you will see it listed under "Rovio Mobile Ltd." but if you tap onto it and view the details page (where you purchase and download the app) it has a blank space under its app name.

My app has the same scenario as Angry Birds Rio. What should I do to fill that gap under the app name on my own app?

(Sorry for not explaining this well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can ever do in this instance is contact Apple. In this case the ITunes Connect team. There is a form in the contact section when you login.

Comment: I will probably do so soon. It seems to be a common problem with a lot of apps.

Comment: But nothing us as users can do, contact them